# How to get incremental rowid by column value in SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

PostgreSQL

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         (CASE
             WHEN "Review".food IS NOT NULL AND "Review".service IS NOT NULL
                 THEN ("Review".food + "Review".service) / 2
             ELSE COALESCE(service, COALESCE(food, NULL)) END) AS rating,
         "venueId" AS item_id,
         "userId" AS user_id
     FROM "Review") AS data
WHERE rating IS NOT NULL
  AND user_id IS NOT NULL
  AND item_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY item_id;
```

This returns an output like this:

[image]

But I need to have one additional column `incremental_id` which will contain id of the each row, bases on the item_id.

For example:

[image]

Where for items with:

```
 item_id = 2  incremental_id = 1;
 item_id = 4  incremental_id = 2;
 item_id = 8  incremental_id = 3;
 item_id = 20 incremental_id = 4;
 item_id = 23 incremental_id = 5;
```

How I need to change my query to get the desired output format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dense_rank](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) window function for this. Keep your query and just add one more expression after the `*`. Here it is:

```sql
SELECT *, dense_rank() over (order by item_id) as incremental_id
FROM -- ... the rest of your query as-it-was ...
```